# AttributeError at /search/ 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'facet'

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, django-taggit

I'm Getting an AttributeError:

```
(AttributeError at /search/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'facet') while setting up custom filters for django-taggit tags with Haystack
```

The search function is working fine when I enter a query like so:
`http://localhost:8000/search/?q=las+vegas`

But the error is showing up when I try to add an other variable for the ptags filter like so: `http://localhost:8000/search/?q=las+vegas&ptags=Solo`

How can I solve this?

Full output:

> ````
> 20:56:46 Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'uvergo.settings'
> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server
> with CTRL-BREAK. Internal Server Error: /search/ Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo_search\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 39, in inner
>     response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo_search\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 187, in _get_response
>     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo_search\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 185, in _get_response
>     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo_search\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py",
> line 68, in view
>     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo_search\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py",
> line 88, in dispatch
>     return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo_search\venv\lib\site-packages\haystack\generic_views.py",
> line 120, in get
>     form = self.get_form(form_class)   File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo_search\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py",
> line 45, in get_form
>     return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())   File "C:\Users\loicq\Desktop\Coding\UVERGO_SEARCH\venv\src\search\views.py",
> line 47, in get_form_kwargs
>     kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()   File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo_search\venv\lib\site-packages\haystack\generic_views.py",
> line 94, in get_form_kwargs
>     kwargs = super(FacetedSearchMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()   File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo_search\venv\lib\site-packages\haystack\generic_views.py",
> line 65, in get_form_kwargs
>     kwargs.update({'searchqueryset': self.get_queryset()})   File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo_search\venv\lib\site-packages\haystack\generic_views.py",
> line 108, in get_queryset
>     qs = qs.facet(field) AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'facet' [02/May/2019 20:57:04] "GET
> /search/?q=las+vegas&ptags=Solo HTTP/1.1" 500 97950 ```
> ````

`Models.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255, default='')

    ptags = TaggableManager()

    image = models.ImageField(default='')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def _ptags(self):
        return [t.name for t in self.ptags.all()]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product',
                       kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My Custom `forms.py`:

```
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
#from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

class FacetedProductSearchForm(FacetedSearchForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        data = dict(kwargs.get("data", []))
        super(FacetedProductSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(FacetedProductSearchForm, self).search()

        ptags = self.request.GET.get('ptags', None)

        if ptags:
            ptags = ptags.split(',')
            sqs = self.queryset.filter(ptags__name__in=ptags).distinct()

        return sqs:
```

I'm passing the custom forms in the views like this:

```
class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):

    form_class = FacetedProductSearchForm
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    facet_fields = ['ptags']
    template_name = 'search_result.html'
    paginate_by = 6
    context_object_name = 'object_list'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
       kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
       kwargs["request"] = self.request
       return kwargs
```

Urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from search.views import HomeView, ProductView, FacetedSearchView, autocomplete
from .settings import MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^product/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProductView.as_view(), name='product'),
    url(r'^search/autocomplete/$', autocomplete),
    url(r'^search/', FacetedSearchView.as_view(), name='haystack_search'),

] + static(MEDIA_URL, document_root=MEDIA_ROOT)
```